# Can't redirect my page to another instead of error report appear

Tags: php, error-handling, header

I have a form already in production and I want to take any possibility to appear an report page for my customer. So I created a "nice" page to redirect when `if` an error report would appear.

What I`ve done was the following:

```
function myErrorHandler() 
{
  header("Location: ./alerta.php");
  die();
}
set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

What has happened with this code is that all results go to that page, even the ones that didn't go to a report page before.
If I just take the `set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");` `off`, the page goes completly normal. I started to think this code is generating an error that makes the function always be called, but couldn't find the code.
Anyone can help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: so use the error handler functionality properly. `function myhandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) { die("Code puked with #$errno:, $errstr in $errfile at $errline"); }` Have php TELL you why it's failing, instead of redirecting elsewhere.

Comment: Good one!
It returned this:
Code puked with #8192:, preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in C:\wamp\www\Pedido 00\class.phpmailer.php at 1736

I am going to have a look in that... Thanks!